# Windows 7 Broken Boot (Complicated Issue)

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive, boot, windows-registry

I have an issue with my old Hard Drive, I got the issue by using CCleaner Registry Cleaner, I thought it could improve my PC's performance but it made it worse.

Whenever I boot/start the PC, it never reaches the point where the welcome screen appears, sometimes it goes to Windows Error Recovery page with unusual font, and all the selections will always lead to a black screen (I think it froze because when I press capslock key the light won't be ON or OFF). and sometimes it will go on that blank black screen directly.

Booting from USB stick or another hard drive will cause the same thing.
there was a time when I waited so long until an error crash screen appeared and I remember it was in System32 folder

I think that fixing the registry in any way will also fix the boot (i have a backup registry file on desktop but I forgot the path names)

Things I tried :

- As I mentioned before, the USB will cause the same issue again, I used USB bootable Windows 7
  but when it shows (Starting windows "with the four orbs animation") and in the middle of the animation, it will directly change the screen to a black/blank screen
- I also tried to test all the options from Windows Error Recovery page but they all will end up the same thing, the weirdest thing is when I boot from Safe Mode, it shows a list of paths until it stops on a specific path (aswardisk.sys) then I wait too long until the crash error code appears again

I am going to put Mediafire folder with the videos (Video #1: Booted from USB led me to Windows Error Recovery)(Video #2: Booted from USB again and everything was normal until the middle of starting windows animation) and the sound of the hard drive from two different mics (Recording_1+Recording_2: crack sounds from hard drive)

- The Folder :
  https://www.mediafire.com/folder/8w200t8h15iq0/pc

Comment: sounds like it could be a bad hard drive since booting other OS results in hang too.

Comment: I am not going through the trouble of downloading videos to view them. Share them in a way they can be watched in a browser directly.

Answer (score 3):

Most registry cleaners cannot fix serious issues. They just clean up junk from old installs and like.

Since your tries with the registry have made things worse, you need to consider trying to rebuild your computer. There is not a Windows 7 Repair Install that will fix this that I know of.

Of course you need to test the physical hard drive before you start. Data could be corrupted and the drive could be fine. So do test.

**(1)** If your computer still has the original Windows 7 Recovery Partition, you can try recovering from that.

**(2)** You can see if you can download Windows 7 from Microsoft. Microsoft is eliminating Windows 7 so not likely. Please see:

[Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/lifecycle/products/windows-7)

**(3)** More likely you will need to see if your computer will run Windows 10 and install that.

[Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10)

If that proves impossible, it may be time to replace the computer.

Comment: The registry was designed in such a way that, "orphaned keys", do not cause a performance issue.  Keys that truly need to be deleted are typically handled by the application that requires them. Programs that perform tasks to remove orphaned keys contained in the registry are "snake oil" products.

Comment: A system restore point is the best bet if they can get it to run.

Comment: Possible but I think probably unlikely in this case